# Let $\phi$ a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. Let $K \leq G$ contain the kernel of $\phi$. Show that $\phi ^{-1}\left( \phi\left( K \right) \right) = K.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Let $\phi$ a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. Let $K \leq G$ contain the kernel of $\phi$. Show that $\phi ^{-1}\left( \phi\left( K \right) \right) = K.$

I have been asked to prove this statement. It looks quite simple to prove, but for some reason I am very stuck trying to prove it. I have taken the approach of trying to show that the sets on each side of the equality are subsets of each other. I have that the set on the left side of the equality is essentially
$$
\left\{ g \in G: \phi\left( g \right)=\phi \left( k \right) \text{ for some }k\in K \right\}
$$
I also see that since the kernel of $\phi$ is in $K$, then we have that
$$
\phi\left( g \right)=e \implies g\in K
$$
I am using the approach of trying to prove that if $ \phi\left( g \right)=\phi \left( k \right) \text{ for some }k\in K $, then $ g \in K $. Obviously the other containment $\left(( K \subseteq \phi ^{-1}\left( \phi\left( K \right) \right) \right)$ is quite trivial, but I cannot see is how to prove the harder containment. I know this is probably very easy, but for some reason I can't work it out. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Multiply $\phi(g)$ with $\phi(k^{-1})$ and see what happens.

Comment: This question is exemplary of a new user and deserves more upvotes, I think. There's plenty of context. It's clear what the problem was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $\phi$ is a homomorphism, so if $\phi(g)=\phi(k)$, then $\phi(gk^{-1})=?$

Comment: Ah okay got it. So $\phi\left( gk^{-1} \right)=\phi\left( g \right)\phi\left( k \right)^{-1}=e$. This implies that $gk^{-1}\in K$, which implies that $g\in K$. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I don't know if you will be able to answer this question, but what was the inspiration for you knowing to examine the object $\phi\left( gk^{-1} \right)$? I'm just unsure why I couldn't see to do it, but you were able to see that would give me the answer?

Comment: Actually I think I have satisfied myself on this question; I can see how I could have thought to do this myself, so no need to answer if you don't feel like it

Comment: Generally, it is always good to keep in mind that $a=b$ is equivalent to $ab^{-1}=e$ in a group (think for example of how this is used in proving that a homomorpism with trivial kernel is injective), so it's natural to rewrite $\phi(g)=\phi(k)$ as $\phi(gk^{-1})=\phi(g)\phi(k)^{-1}=e$. My hint came from "working backwards", in that sense. It's also good to note that you hadn't yet used the property that $\phi$ is a homomorphism anywhere (and surely that has to be used somewhere).